# How to display HTTPS contents [Using Proxy]

Tags: proxy, tls-intercept

I'm a beginner at proxy traffic stuff and I'm struggling here with [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com)

I'm trying to 'intercept traffic'. I have an HTTPS page and I want to display the data from the content (inside Charles proxy).

ALL my https are returning `<unknown>`

I'm currently using Firefox. I'm not manually setting the proxy configs.
I know it may seem like a dumb question but I could not figure out how to solve this.

...I know it has to do with SSL but can't resolve that problem by myself

Comment: Have you read the [Documentation] (https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/proxy-settings/) and this one too [SSL](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/)?

Comment: Yes, and i think i cant go further because the way it is writen

Comment: You download the certificate on the SSL link and that certificate you import it to your browser, in that way you can capture all the traffic. you can check it with [control](http://control.charles/)

Comment: I downloaded it but it does not work, keeps returning unkown from https request

Comment: Then you might need to confirm that you imported the certificate into Firefox properly. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Fabian and Schroeder, one has to install/trust the SSL certificate from the proxy itself (for example [here](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/proxy/options/installing-ca-certificate) is how it's done with Burp, a local proxy like Charles).

As per [documentation](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/), install the Charles certificate:

> Visit https://chls.pro/ssl in Firefox. You will be presented with a certificate import dialog. Tick the option "Trust this CA to identify websites" and complete the import.

In Firefox you can either accept a prompted certificate when visiting an untrusted website (like your local proxy https://chls.pro/ssl) or import it manually via a (.PEM) file, like [here](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/proxy-settings/):

> In Charles go to the Help menu and choose "SSL Proxying > Install Charles Root Certificate".

In Firefox you can go to Preferences menu, then type certificate in the search box, click View certificate... then Your Certificates, then Import...

It can depend on your platform how you import certificates (e.g. Windows "installs" them).

To isolate the issue, are you able to first intercept HTTP traffic?